# Failed to run Tarantool replication

Tags: replication

I'm trying to reproduce the tarantool master-replication from [documentation](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/book/replication/repl_bootstrap/#master-replica-bootstrap)

so I made `master/master.lua`, `rep1/rep1.lua`, `rep2/rep2.lua`, cd for each directory and run it, but it shows something like this (for 10+ minutes, no progress):

```
@ /tmp/master
└─[0] <> tarantool master.lua
2021-05-21 21:12:43.941 [884153] main/103/master.lua C> Tarantool 2.7.2-14-ga308ba8e2
2021-05-21 21:12:43.941 [884153] main/103/master.lua C> log level 5
2021-05-21 21:12:43.941 [884153] main/103/master.lua I> wal/engine cleanup is paused
2021-05-21 21:12:43.941 [884153] main/103/master.lua I> mapping 268435456 bytes for memtx tuple arena...
2021-05-21 21:12:43.941 [884153] main/103/master.lua I> Actual slab_alloc_factor calculated on the basis of desired slab_alloc_factor = 1.044274
2021-05-21 21:12:43.941 [884153] main/103/master.lua I> mapping 134217728 bytes for vinyl tuple arena...
2021-05-21 21:12:43.942 [884153] main/103/master.lua I> instance uuid b78ffe3e-d8d3-4f98-b213-dae4ac0b6858
2021-05-21 21:12:43.942 [884153] iproto/101/main I> binary: bound to 0.0.0.0:13301
2021-05-21 21:12:43.942 [884153] main/103/master.lua I> connecting to 2 replicas
2021-05-21 21:12:43.942 [884153] main/111/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:33301 I> can't connect to master
2021-05-21 21:12:43.942 [884153] main/111/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:33301 coio.cc:108 !> SystemError connect, called on fd 17, aka 127.0.0.1:59352: Connection refused
2021-05-21 21:12:43.942 [884153] main/111/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:33301 I> will retry every 1.00 second
2021-05-21 21:12:43.942 [884153] main/110/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:23301 I> can't connect to master
2021-05-21 21:12:43.942 [884153] main/110/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:23301 coio.cc:108 !> SystemError connect, called on fd 16, aka 127.0.0.1:49188: Connection refused
2021-05-21 21:12:43.942 [884153] main/110/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:23301 I> will retry every 1.00 second
2021-05-21 21:12:45.944 [884153] main/110/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:23301 I> remote master e242f602-6591-4eb5-9194-f64d7541ea67 at 127.0.0.1:23301 running Tarantool 2.7.2
2021-05-21 21:12:47.945 [884153] main/111/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:33301 I> remote master 7d21d786-f0fa-440c-8b19-4c2f66fe47fe at 127.0.0.1:33301 running Tarantool 2.7.2
2021-05-21 21:12:47.945 [884153] main/103/master.lua I> connected to 2 replicas
2021-05-21 21:12:47.945 [884153] main/111/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:33301 I> failed to authenticate
2021-05-21 21:12:47.945 [884153] main/111/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:33301 box.cc:2381 E> ER_LOADING: Instance bootstrap hasn't finished yet
2021-05-21 21:12:47.945 [884153] main/111/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:33301 I> will retry every 1.00 second

@ /tmp/rep1
└─[0] <> tarantool rep1.lua
2021-05-21 21:12:45.793 [884163] main/103/rep1.lua C> Tarantool 2.7.2-14-ga308ba8e2
2021-05-21 21:12:45.793 [884163] main/103/rep1.lua C> log level 5
2021-05-21 21:12:45.793 [884163] main/103/rep1.lua I> wal/engine cleanup is paused
2021-05-21 21:12:45.793 [884163] main/103/rep1.lua I> mapping 268435456 bytes for memtx tuple arena...
2021-05-21 21:12:45.793 [884163] main/103/rep1.lua I> Actual slab_alloc_factor calculated on the basis of desired slab_alloc_factor = 1.044274
2021-05-21 21:12:45.793 [884163] main/103/rep1.lua I> mapping 134217728 bytes for vinyl tuple arena...
2021-05-21 21:12:45.793 [884163] main/103/rep1.lua I> instance uuid e242f602-6591-4eb5-9194-f64d7541ea67
2021-05-21 21:12:45.793 [884163] iproto/101/main I> binary: bound to 0.0.0.0:23301
2021-05-21 21:12:45.793 [884163] main/103/rep1.lua I> connecting to 2 replicas
2021-05-21 21:12:45.794 [884163] main/111/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:33301 I> can't connect to master
2021-05-21 21:12:45.794 [884163] main/111/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:33301 coio.cc:108 !> SystemError connect, called on fd 17, aka 127.0.0.1:59388: Connection refused
2021-05-21 21:12:45.794 [884163] main/111/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:33301 I> will retry every 1.00 second
2021-05-21 21:12:45.794 [884163] main/110/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:13301 I> remote master b78ffe3e-d8d3-4f98-b213-dae4ac0b6858 at 127.0.0.1:13301 running Tarantool 2.7.2
2021-05-21 21:12:47.796 [884163] main/111/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:33301 I> remote master 7d21d786-f0fa-440c-8b19-4c2f66fe47fe at 127.0.0.1:33301 running Tarantool 2.7.2
2021-05-21 21:12:47.796 [884163] main/103/rep1.lua I> connected to 2 replicas
2021-05-21 21:12:47.796 [884163] main/110/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:13301 I> failed to authenticate
2021-05-21 21:12:47.796 [884163] main/110/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:13301 box.cc:2381 E> ER_LOADING: Instance bootstrap hasn't finished yet
2021-05-21 21:12:47.796 [884163] main/110/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:13301 I> will retry every 1.00 second

@ /tmp/rep2
└─[0] <> tarantool rep2.lua
2021-05-21 21:12:47.435 [884173] main/103/rep2.lua C> Tarantool 2.7.2-14-ga308ba8e2
2021-05-21 21:12:47.435 [884173] main/103/rep2.lua C> log level 5
2021-05-21 21:12:47.435 [884173] main/103/rep2.lua I> wal/engine cleanup is paused
2021-05-21 21:12:47.435 [884173] main/103/rep2.lua I> mapping 268435456 bytes for memtx tuple arena...
2021-05-21 21:12:47.435 [884173] main/103/rep2.lua I> Actual slab_alloc_factor calculated on the basis of desired slab_alloc_factor = 1.044274
2021-05-21 21:12:47.435 [884173] main/103/rep2.lua I> mapping 134217728 bytes for vinyl tuple arena...
2021-05-21 21:12:47.436 [884173] main/103/rep2.lua I> instance uuid 7d21d786-f0fa-440c-8b19-4c2f66fe47fe
2021-05-21 21:12:47.436 [884173] iproto/101/main I> binary: bound to 0.0.0.0:33301
2021-05-21 21:12:47.436 [884173] main/103/rep2.lua I> connecting to 2 replicas
2021-05-21 21:12:47.437 [884173] main/110/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:13301 I> remote master b78ffe3e-d8d3-4f98-b213-dae4ac0b6858 at 127.0.0.1:13301 running Tarantool 2.7.2
2021-05-21 21:12:47.437 [884173] main/111/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:23301 I> remote master e242f602-6591-4eb5-9194-f64d7541ea67 at 127.0.0.1:23301 running Tarantool 2.7.2
2021-05-21 21:12:47.437 [884173] main/103/rep2.lua I> connected to 2 replicas
2021-05-21 21:12:47.437 [884173] main/110/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:13301 I> failed to authenticate
2021-05-21 21:12:47.437 [884173] main/110/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:13301 box.cc:2381 E> ER_LOADING: Instance bootstrap hasn't finished yet
2021-05-21 21:12:47.437 [884173] main/110/applier/replicator@127.0.0.1:13301 I> will retry every 1.00 second
```

the code are here:

`master.lua`

```lua
box.cfg{
  listen = 13301,
        replication = {'replicator:password@127.0.0.1:23301',  -- master URI
                 'replicator:password@127.0.0.1:33301'}, -- replica URI
  read_only = false
}
box.once("schema", function()
   box.schema.user.create('replicator', {password = 'password'})
   box.schema.user.grant('replicator', 'replication') -- grant replication role
   box.schema.space.create("test")
   box.space.test:create_index("primary")
   print('box.once executed on master')
end)
```

`rep1.lua`

```lua
box.cfg{
  listen = 23301,
  replication = {'replicator:password@127.0.0.1:13301',  -- master URI
                 'replicator:password@127.0.0.1:33301'}, -- replica URI
  read_only = true
}
box.once("schema", function()
   box.schema.user.create('replicator', {password = 'password'})
   box.schema.user.grant('replicator', 'replication') -- grant replication role
   box.schema.space.create("test")
   box.space.test:create_index("primary")
   print('box.once executed on replica 1')
end)
```

`rep2.lua`

```lua
box.cfg{
  listen = 33301,
  replication = {'replicator:password@127.0.0.1:13301',  -- master URI
                 'replicator:password@127.0.0.1:23301'}, -- replica URI
  read_only = true
}
box.once("schema", function()
   box.schema.user.create('replicator', {password = 'password'})
   box.schema.user.grant('replicator', 'replication') -- grant replication role
   box.schema.space.create("test")
   box.space.test:create_index("primary")
   print('box.once executed on replica 2')
end)
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, my bad, first replication line should be the master, so it should be something like this:

```
        replication = {'replicator:password@127.0.0.1:13301',  -- master URI
                 'replicator:password@127.0.0.1:23301', -- replica URI
                 'replicator:password@127.0.0.1:33301'}, -- replica URI
```